# Can I associate my command history based on my cwd

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

I often navigate between multiple directories in a bash session. Sometimes upto 4. For each directory I am in I often have an exclusive set of commands that I fire and this set can be between 7 and 10 commands. I was wondering if it is possible to create an association between my bash command history and the cwd in which those commands were fired. Appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: can you give an example? why don't you use `pwd`? (with backquotes)

Comment: For example: cd adir -> cmd_for_a1, cmd_for_a2 cmd_for_a3, ... followed by cd bdir -> cmd_for_b1,... and so on. This means that my command history is clearly associated with where I am in terms of working dir. I just want to make it easy for me to bring back those commands based on my cwd.

Comment: In that case, wouldn't it be easier to have a script in your path that woulc issue different commands considering the \`pwd` where you launched it from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following re-definition for `cd` and and put these lines into `.bashrc`:

```
            HISTFILE=$HOME/.bash_history.`echo $PWD|sed -e 's/\//_/g'`
            cd () {
                history -a
                command cd "$@"
                HISTFILE=$HOME/.bash_history.`echo $PWD|sed -e 's/\//_/g'`
                history -c
                history -r
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PROMPT_COMMAND` to check `$PWD` and take appropriate action, something like this:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='if [[ $PWD =~ /usr/share ]]; then echo take action in /usr/share; fi'
```